# Can Parent Tag styling taking precedence on similar styling at child tag on hover

Tags: html, css

I am facing some styling problems. How to apply the parent tag styling on the child tag (which as its own) on hover?
Taking a simple example to focus on the problem only.

```css
.outer:hover {
  background: yellow;
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
}

.inner {
  background: red;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">Something</div>
</div>
```

Expected output;
Normally the background is red (from the inner class) but on hover I need to override it with the styling of the parent tag (outer class, backgroud: yellow).

The outer and inner class have to be in those tags only.
http://jsfiddle.net/P7c9q/2209/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use CSS variable:

```css
.outer:hover {
  background: yellow;
  --c:transparent;
}

.inner {
  background: var(--c,red);
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">Something</div>
</div>
```

Or use inherit:

```css
.outer:hover {
  background: yellow;
}
.outer:hover .inner {
  background:inherit;
}

.inner {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">Something</div>
</div>
```

Comment: OK let me give the exact problem.
http://jsfiddle.net/P7c9q/2253/

here the first column is red (styling at td level), however on hover the enter row shud be yellow (styling at tr level). If the focus/pointer is anywhere on the row than the entire row shud be yellow (styling from parent).

Comment: @Hemal and the solution I provided fix you issue http://jsfiddle.net/P7c9q/2255/ ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I need to brush up my css skills :)

Answer (score 1):

Use :not selector to override with parent style when :hover `.inner:not(:hover)`
When it's not hovered over it will use it's own child style, when hoverd over - parent

Comment: OK let me give the exact problem.
http://jsfiddle.net/P7c9q/2253/

here the first column is red (styling at td level), however on hover the enter row shud be yellow (styling at tr level). If the focus/pointer is anywhere on the row than the entire row shud be yellow (styling from parent).

Comment: @Hemal  you can use additional style: .row:hover .column { background: inherit; }

Comment: Thanks a lot. I need to brush up my css skills :)

Comment: @Hemal it's okay :)